# Solve $m \equiv 2014^{2014}\mod 17$ for the least positive value of $m$

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Find the least positive value of $m$ so that $m \equiv 2014^{2014}\mod 17$.

I did an euclidean algorithm between $2014$ and $17$,

$$\begin{align}
2014 &= 118 × 17 + 8\\
17 &= 2 × 8 + 1\\
8 &= 8 × 1 + 0
\end{align}$$

and

$$−2⋅2014+237\times17=1$$

Now using Fermat's little theorem, $17$ being a prime number, I use the form $a^{p - 1}  \equiv 1 \mod p$

and further more, we know that, $2014 = 16 \times 125 + 14$

so this implies that $((2014)^{16})^{125} + 2014^{14} = 1^{125} + 2014^{14}$

Now am left to struggle with $2014^{14}$ which is still an enormously big figure. How do i go about it?

Comment: Hint:  $a\equiv b \pmod p\implies a^k\equiv b^k\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with ${\alpha}^{\beta} \pmod a$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being "big numbers", you have to reduce both.

### First, let's get rid of the base $2014$.

You noticed that $2014=118\times17+8$

The value of $118$ is actually useless here, all we need is $2014 = 17\times k + 8$

From there you have: $2014 \equiv 8 \pmod {17} $

Thus, $2014^{2014} \equiv 8^{2014} \pmod {17} $

Now, you have to compute $8^{2014} \pmod {17} $, and for this:

### Get rid of the exponent $2014$

To do that, you have to find a number such that $8^a \equiv \pm1 \pmod {17}$. There may be some algorithms for that, but if you have a calculator with you, trial and error can sometimes be the best way to proceed. You'll find that $8^4 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$

Note that $2014 = 503 \times 4 + 2$

Therefore, $8^{2014} = {(8^4)}^{503}\times8^2 \equiv {(-1)}^{503} \times 64 \equiv -64 \equiv 4 \pmod {17} $

Comment: $8^{4^{503}}\neq (8^4)^{503}$

Comment: @Jakobian Nice catch, thanks!

Comment: Its a very nice technique. But what if i dont have a calculator. I know u pointed out that there could be an algorithm out there...anyone that has a quick technique?

Comment: You should have a look at B. Goddard answer, he did the same thing as me in the first part, and used the Fermat's little theorem for the second part. It seems to be faster than what I did, and there is no need for trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

Your first calculation shows that $2014 \equiv 8 \pmod{17}$, so you have

$$2014^{2014} \equiv 8^{2014} \pmod{17}.$$

Your second calculation shows that $2014 \equiv 14 \pmod{16},$ so the above

$$\equiv 8^{14} \equiv 2^{42} \equiv (2^4)^{10}2^2 \equiv (-1)^{10}4 \equiv 4 \pmod{17}.$$

Comment: We could also use Fermat's little theorem again, after seeing that $8=2^3$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
2014^{2014}   &\equiv 8^{2014} \\&\equiv 8 \cdot 8^{3^{671}} \\ &\equiv 8 \cdot 512^{671}\\ &\equiv 8 \cdot 2^{671} \\& \equiv  8 \cdot 2^{4^{167}}\cdot 2^3 \\ &\equiv 8 \cdot 16^{167}\cdot 2^3\\
&\equiv 8 \cdot (-1)^{167} \cdot 8\\
&\equiv 64 \cdot (-1)\\
&\equiv -13 \\
& \equiv 4 \mod 17
\end{align}$$